# How to Get matching records using Exists statement along with a condition on the main table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, exists

I have a problem regarding sql 'exists' statement and I will highly appreciate any kind of help.
Let me explain you what I need to accomplish.

I have two tables where I would like to get matching records from table1 which also exits in table2. Till this, it is simple. However, I also want to get those records from table1 along with matching records which has a particular column NULL in Table1. In other words I need to get those records from Table1 either they exist in Table2 or they have a specific column NULL. I wrote the following query to accomplish this.

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1(ID INT, Column2 INT NULL)

CREATE TABLE #Table2(ID INT)

INSERT INTO #Table1 VALUES(1, NULL)

INSERT INTO #Table2 VALUES(2)

select * from #Table1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL from #Table2 where #Table2.ID = #Table1.ID OR #Table1.Column2 IS NULL)

DROP TABLE #Table1;

DROP TABLE #Table2;
```

This query works when Table2 is not empty. However, if Table2 is empty then IS NULL condition does not work.

In order to resolve this I also tried adding a dummy record in case Table2 is empty by adding a union, but it does not resolve my problem either because there will always a record when I should get 0 records.

Like this

```
select * from #Table1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT ID WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #Table2) 

UNION 

SELECT NULL from #Table2 where #Table2.ID = #Table1.ID OR #Table1.Column2 IS NULL)
```

Note: I know this can be solved using joins but I would like to solve it using Exists statement because this is the part of a large system which simply cannot be converted to joins. I have given the above as a simple scenario.

Any kind of help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Will this work?

```
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 from #Table2 where #Table2.ID = #Table1.ID) OR #Table1.Column2 IS NULL
```

Comment: Please see my comment on the first answer.

Comment: You do not need to write `IS NULL` multiple times, you could do: `where (your_bunch_of_exists_statement) OR (#Table1.column2 IS NULL)`

Comment: Actually there are many columns that I need to check for NULL. Every exists contains a separate column to be checked for Null. sorry at the beginning I posted the question in a simple way

Answer (score 0):

Move the condition outside the `EXISTS`.  It is closer to how you describe the problem anyway:

```
select t1.*
from #Table1 t1.
WHERE t1.Column2 IS NULL OR
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 from #Table2 t2 where t2.ID = t1.ID);
```

Notes:

- Although `EXISTS (SELECT NULL . . . )` is allowed an works, I find it highly misleading.  In practice, `NULL` often represents *missing* values so the result is a bit of cognitive dissonance.  Besides, `SELECT 1` is easier to type.
- I recommend table aliases; they make the query easier to write and to read.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, I am afraid that this is not going to be of help because the actual scenario I have many Exists linked with AND. Therefore, I cannot take the IsNull condition out of exits. The real query is like this.

FROM  #TempOrders temp
WHERE
exists (  )  AND  exists (  )  AND  exists (  )  AND  exists ( )  AND  exists ( )  AND  exists ()

Comment: @youngseagul . . . So?  Just use multiple `exists` expressions and put parentheses around them.